# How to change a Jitsi IFrame API domain?

Tags: javascript, html, jitsi, jitsi-meet

So I'm using the Jitsi Meet IFrame API and am looking to get the additional customization that comes from hosting it on my own server...the problem is I'm kinda of a newbie when it comes to this stuff and am not sure exactly what that means. I think I have to change the defined domain from 'meet.jit.si' to my own domain but am not sure how to go about that. How can I change the domain to something else? Here's the code for the embedded Jitsi meeting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js"></script>
    <script>
        var domain = "meet.jit.si";
        var options = {
            roomName: "TestRoomName",
            width: 800,
            height: 700,
            parentNode: undefined,
            configOverwrite: {},
            interfaceConfigOverwrite: {}
        }
        var api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change following lines:

```
<script src="https://{yourdomain.com}/external_api.js"></script>

var domain = "yourdomain.com";
```

Let me know if it works!